# Нужно чтобы первая программа сама заходила во вторую и нажимала button1

Tags: delphi

Есть две программы, обе написанные на delphi. Нужно чтобы первая программа сама заходила во вторую и нажимала `button1`.

Так открывается программа

```
ShellExecute(handle,'open','Test.exe',nil,nil,SW_SHOW);
```

А как сделать чтоб еще и нажимала на кнопку `button1`

Если можно код.

Comment: Через WinApi, SendMessage, по-моему

Comment: Нужно найти окошко целевой программы (windows handle), найти handle кнопки и заслать ему, как подсказывают выше, мессагу. Учите Winapi. Может что на этом сайте найдёте что-нибудь  готовоеhttp://delphikingdom.ru/. Такой же старый как delphi, а старые люди знали как такое дело провернуть. (Сам знал, но забыл:)

Answer (score 3):

Если Вы можете вносить правки в обе программы, то можно сделать таким образом, чтобы первая программа в отдельном потоке ожидала некоего события, которое пошлет ему другое приложение, при наступлении которого первое приложение нажимало бы кнопку. Такое взаимодействие можно организовать, например, с помощью мьютексов, сокетов или какой-нибудь другой технологии (см. межпроцессное взаимодействие).

Если же Вам нужен результат, а не текст программы, то можно воспользоваться какой-нибудь готовой программой для автоматизации нажатия кнопок, например, [Sikuli Script](http://www.sikuli.org/).

Answer (score 2):

попробуйте следуюший код

```
Procedure ClickSomewhere(WindowName, WindowCaption: PChar; X,Y:Integer);
Var
  hParent : HWND;
Begin
 hParent := FindWindow(WindowName, WindowCaption);
 if hParent<>0 Then
  Begin
   BringWindowToTop(hParent);
   Application.ProcessMessages; // not sure that is useful
   SendMessage(hParent, BM_CLICK, X,Y);
  End;
End;
```

тут нужно указать название второй программы через `WindowCaption`

`X`,`Y` это координаты куда надо нажать в форме

Comment: Желательно findwindow продолжить до самой кнопки. В дельфи вроде была утилитка, позволяющая просматривать всё дерево окошек любой программы. С её помощью определить путь поиска и закодировать его в своей программке-нажималке.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй через имитацию клика мыши. Лично я не вижу других вариантов. Только есть одно условие, твоя вторая программа обязательно запускаться в определенном месте на экране.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

если программы обе ваши. то в ведомой поставьте фокус по умолчанию на нужную кнопку. и после вызова ShellExecute посылаете ей ентер.
еще вариант если обе программы ваши то в ведомой программе пропищите запуск с ключем который будет нажимать нужную вам кнопку. а запускайте с ShellExecute уже с нужным ключем.